# Griddbs data partitioning implementation and impact on performance

Tags: distributed-system, griddb

Griddb uses a distributed architecture that partitions data across multiple nodes for scalability and fault tolerance. What are the different partitioning strategies used by Griddb, and how do they affect performance and data availability? Additionally, how does Griddb handle the rebalancing of partitions when nodes are added or removed from the cluster?